# Question Categorization Dataset(s)

Tags: nlp, dataset

I'm looking for a dataset or group of datasets I could combine that would contain numerous examples of the following types of question categories.

- free response *(ex: What is the capital of Portugal?)*
- yes or no *(ex: Do you want me to turn off the lights?)*
- numerical *(ex: What is the temperature in here?)*
- conjunction *(ex: Do you want the red or the blue blanket?)*

I've found that there is a ton of datasets for free response questions, and a couple for yes/no questions, but almost none for numeral and conjunction questions. Any suggestions?